# Using Unity Dependency Injection with WCF services

Tags: wcf, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have the following after doing some research on other questions:

**MyServiceHost:**

```
public class MyServiceHost : ServiceHost
{
    public MyServiceHost(IUnityContainer container, Type serviceType, params Uri[] baseAddresses)
        : base(serviceType, baseAddresses)
    {
        if (container == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("container");
        }
        foreach (var cd in this.ImplementedContracts.Values)
        {
            cd.Behaviors.Add(new DependencyInjectionInstanceProvider(container));
        }
    }
}
```

**DependencyInjectionInstanceProvider:**

```
public class DependencyInjectionInstanceProvider : IInstanceProvider, IContractBehavior 
{     
    private readonly IUnityContainer container;      
    public DependencyInjectionInstanceProvider(IUnityContainer container)     
    {         
        if (container == null)         
        {             
            throw new ArgumentNullException("container");         
        }          

        this.container = container;     

    }      

    #region IInstanceProvider Members      

    public object GetInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext, Message message)     
    {         
        return this.GetInstance(instanceContext);     
    }      

    public object GetInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext)     
    {         
        var serviceType = instanceContext.Host.Description.ServiceType;         
        return this.container.Resolve(serviceType);     
    }      

    public void ReleaseInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext, object instance)    
    {        
        this.container.Teardown(instance);     
    }      

    #endregion      

    #region IContractBehavior Members      

    public void AddBindingParameters(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)     
    {     
    }      

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)     
    {     
    }      

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, DispatchRuntime dispatchRuntime)    
    {         
        dispatchRuntime.InstanceProvider = this;     
    }      

    public void Validate(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint)     
    {     
    }     
    #endregion 

}
```

**MyServiceHostFactory:**

```
    public class MyServiceHostFactory : ServiceHostFactory
{
    private readonly IUnityContainer container;     
    protected override ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses) 
    { 
        return new MyServiceHost(this.container, serviceType, baseAddresses); 
    }
}
```

**Email Service with an attempted Constructor Injection:**

```
public class EmailValidator : IEmailValidator
{
    private IFakeDAL fakeDAL;

    public EmailValidator(IFakeDAL fakeDAL)
    {
        this.fakeDAL = fakeDAL;
    }

    public bool ValidateAddress(string emailAddress)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Validating: {0}", emailAddress);

        string pattern = @"^([0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*@(([0-9a-zA-Z])+([-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9})$";
        return Regex.IsMatch(emailAddress, pattern);
    }
}
```

**My Console Host to start the Service:**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Type serviceType = typeof(EmailValidator);
        Uri serviceUri = new Uri("http://localhost:8080/");

        MyServiceHostFactory shf = new MyServiceHostFactory();
        ServiceHost host = shf.CreateServiceHost(serviceType, serviceUri);
        //ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(serviceType, serviceUri);
        host.Open();
```

My problem resides in the console host logic.  The CreateServiceHost call has a syntax error due to the first argument expecting a Constructor string and not a Type.  Which I don't understand since it does accept a Type parameter.  In addition to that I don't understand where I should be mapping IFakeDAL to a concrete class.  Can I do that in an app.config file or should I register that somewhere else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ServiceHostFactory` is for hosting in IIS. In self hosting you should use your derived `ServiceHost` directly. [Here](http://weblogs.asp.net/fabio/archive/2009/03/24/inversion-of-control-with-wcf-and-unity.aspx) you have whole example including Unity configuration.

Comment: Thanks.  It looks like a very good example.  I might actually figure this out. :)

Answer (score 3):

I´m using the following classes in my windows service to create WCF services and inject dependencies to it using unity.

**UnityInstanceProvider:**

```
internal class UnityInstanceProvider : IInstanceProvider {

    private readonly IUnityContainer container;
    private readonly Type contractType;

    public UnityInstanceProvider(IUnityContainer container, Type contractType) {
        this.container = container;
        this.contractType = contractType;
    }

    public object GetInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext) {
        return GetInstance(instanceContext, null);
    }

    public object GetInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext, Message message) {
        return container.Resolve(contractType);
    }

    public void ReleaseInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext, object instance) {
        container.Teardown(instance);
    }
}
```

**UnityServiceBehavior:**

```
public class UnityServiceBehavior : IServiceBehavior {

    private readonly IUnityContainer container;

    public UnityServiceBehavior(IUnityContainer container) {
        this.container = container;
    }

    public void Validate(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase) {
    }

    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase, Collection<ServiceEndpoint> endpoints, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters) {
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase) {
        foreach (ChannelDispatcher channelDispatcher in serviceHostBase.ChannelDispatchers) {
            foreach (EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher in channelDispatcher.Endpoints) {
                if (endpointDispatcher.ContractName != "IMetadataExchange") {
                    string contractName = endpointDispatcher.ContractName;
                    ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint = serviceDescription.Endpoints.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Contract.Name == contractName);
                    endpointDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.InstanceProvider = new UnityInstanceProvider(this.container, serviceEndpoint.Contract.ContractType);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**UnityServiceHost:**

```
public class UnityServiceHost : ServiceHost {

    private IUnityContainer unityContainer;

    public UnityServiceHost(IUnityContainer unityContainer, Type serviceType)
        : base(serviceType) {
        this.unityContainer = unityContainer;
    }

    protected override void OnOpening() {
        base.OnOpening();

        if (this.Description.Behaviors.Find<UnityServiceBehavior>() == null) {
            this.Description.Behaviors.Add(new UnityServiceBehavior(this.unityContainer));
        }
    }
}
```

With this classes you can do the following (The configuration of services is done in .config):

```
UnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
UnityServiceHost serviceHost = new UnityServiceHost(container, typeof("Type of Service to host"));
serviceHost.Open();
```

Comment: So you are mapping to the concrete classes in your config file?

Comment: Do you mind showing your configuration of a service in the config file?

Answer (score 1):

The [CreateServiceHost method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms554316.aspx) expects an array of `Uri` instances, so try this instead:

```
ServiceHost host = shf.CreateServiceHost(serviceType, new[] { serviceUri });
```

You can map interfaces to types in either XML or code, but I'd recommend code, since XML has too high a maintenance overhead.

The `Main` method is an excellent [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot.aspx), but if you want to configure the container at that level, you'll need to pass it from the `Main` method to `MyServiceHostFactory` - which is perfectly fine when you host the service in a console application, but will not work if you want to host it in IIS, where `MyServiceHostFactory` [should be the Composition Root, since IIS requires a default constructor](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/05/17/ServiceHostFactoryLifetime.aspx).

Comment: +1 for comment on where composition root should be. BTW, loving the book Mark.