# Simplify Using IOC Container with WCF

Tags: wcf, iis, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ioc-container

In [article](http://www.i-avington.com/Posts/Post/usng-unity-with-a-wcf-service) after [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7355501/using-unity-dependency-injection-with-wcf-services) after [article](http://weblogs.asp.net/fabio/archive/2009/03/24/inversion-of-control-with-wcf-and-unity.aspx), any discussion of using an IOC Container (Unity, Windsor, etc.) with IIS involves the creation of a custom ServiceHostFactory and a custom ServiceHost.

The only reason I can see for that, is so that a custom service behavior, with an IInstanceProvider-related payload, can be applied to all services.  So I'm trying to understand why the whole affair is not simplified by having an [anonymous service configuration](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/wcf/thread/c6678f2e-0234-4d47-86d9-3efdc2e6c682).  Such configuration would allow a custom behavior to be applied to all services without using a custom ServiceHostFactory and custom Service Host.

That said, the only reason I can imagine a custom service host would be necessary is if the custom IInstanceProvider is recycled with each WCF instance or context instance.  Certainly I would want IOC Container bindings to be established only once for each launch of my IIS ServiceHost rather than repeatedly or irregularly.

If my custom IInstanceProvider is indeed being recycled sporadically, then I could put my IOC Container into a custom service host - to insure that it will stick around as long as possible.

But again, if my custom IInstanceProvider will last as long as the in-built service host, then why not just skip the custom service host factory and custom service host?

In fact, taking this a bit further, if I were to put my IOC Container into a static member of my custom IInstanceProvider, then it wouldn't matter if the IInstanceProvider was being recycled irregularly.  It comes full-circle: why do I need or want a custom ServiceHostFactory and custom ServiceHost to use an IOC Container with WCF?

Answer (score 2):

Well. That's because most IoC/WCF integrations (like [mine](https://github.com/jgauffin/griffin.container)) does more than just creating your service (with it's dependencies).

**Custom lifetimes / Disposal**

Everything should get clean up properly when a request have ended. Your servcice and your IoC classes uses different lifetimes.

The end of a request can't be detected just with the help of an `InstanceProvider`.

**IContractBehavior / IServiceBehavior**

You can register behaviors in the container and [automatically](https://github.com/jgauffin/Griffin.Container/blob/master/Source/Griffin.Container.Wcf/ServiceLocatorServiceHost.cs) get them added to your WCF service.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, i'm a fan of using a design where you don't need any `ServiceHostFactory`, `ServiceHost`, `ServiceBehavior`, and `InstanceProvider` combination and where you don't have to register the factory in your .svc file. I like my WCF service as just a really thin layer on top of a message passing architecture, and this saves you from using this WCF integration stuff. You can read more about such a design [here](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=95).

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question! The only reason I could think of for doing it this way is that you don't want to clutter up your app.config with items that are never going to change (i.e. the IoC container used by your WCF services). I try to restrict my use of the app.config to things that an end-user / developer might conceivably want to change without recompiling (in most cases, not much). This makes it more readable, and it is usually easier to specify configuration programmatically as there is better support for intellisense and compile-time checking within program code as opposed to configuration files.

However, this argument might not apply to the first article you linked to, because they're actually setting up their IoC container through the app.config. So it might be a double standard in this case. I've never really understood why people want to set up all their dependencies through external configuration files anyway. Storing static configuration in the app.config just seems like overkill to me in most cases.